# Angular SPA PWA - Safari iOS Tab Icon don't change

Tags: ios, angular, safari, icons, favicon

I'm creating an Angular SPA PWA and I have a problem with the Safari iOS Tab, because it doesn't change from Angular favicon, but in Android and Pc it do.

I have tried to do the same that [safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW1) like this in my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Unmatched Pairings</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icons/icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-128x128.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-384x384.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-512x512.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
<foo>
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:center; margin-bottom: 1rem; align-items: center;">
    <div>Icons from:</div>
    <div><a href="https://www.fontawesome.com" title="Fontawesome" target="_blank">https://www.fontawesome.com</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.freepngimg.com" title="Flaticon" target="_blank">https://www.freepngimg.com</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.flaticon.com" title="Flaticon" target="_blank">https://www.flaticon.com</a></div>
  </div>  
</foo>
</html>
```

Including the icons in the manifest.webmanifest file:

```
 {
  "name": "Unmatched Pairings",
  "short_name": "Unmatched Pairings",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}
```

And removing the favicon.ico file.

Before all deployments I have deleted the safari cache.

But it continue without change:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvN00.jpg

Could you help me? please.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have achived to show the tab icon in Mac OS Safari, iOS Chrome and iOS Firefox but not in iOS Safari, the Angular icon remains in it.

This is now the index.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Unmatched Pairings</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="assets/icons/icon-512x512.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="384x384" href="assets/icons/icon-384x384.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="assets/icons/icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="152x152" href="assets/icons/icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="144x144" href="assets/icons/icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="128x128" href="assets/icons/icon-128x128.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="assets/icons/icon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="72x72" href="assets/icons/icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/icons/icon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/icons/icon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="assets/icons/icon-512x512.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="assets/icons/icon-384x384.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="assets/icons/icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="assets/icons/icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="assets/icons/icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="assets/icons/icon-128x128.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="assets/icons/icon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/icons/icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="32x32" href="assets/icons/icon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="16x16" href="assets/icons/icon-16x16.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
<foo>
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:center; margin-bottom: 1rem; align-items: center;">
    <div>Icons from:</div>
    <div><a href="https://www.fontawesome.com" title="Fontawesome" target="_blank">https://www.fontawesome.com</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.freepngimg.com" title="Flaticon" target="_blank">https://www.freepngimg.com</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.flaticon.com" title="Flaticon" target="_blank">https://www.flaticon.com</a></div>
  </div>  
</foo>
</html>
```

Could anyone tell me why iOS Safari tab icon don't change?

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Comment: Please don't add questions in the answers section. Edit your question if it needs to be updated